# Delete multiple s3 bucket files with Last Modified date condition

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you delete multiple S3 files with **Last Modified** date condition?

I have this folder structure on s3.

- dentca-lab-dev-sample

  - 2019-03-13

    - file1 Last modified: Mar 13, 2019 2:34:06 PM GMT-0700
    - file2 Last modified: Mar 13, 2019 3:18:01 PM GMT-0700
    - file3 Last modified: Mar 13, 2019 2:34:30 PM GMT-0700
    - file4 Last modified: Mar 13, 2019 2:32:40 PM GMT-0700

and wanted to delete a file (this is just a sample) less than  `Mar 13, 2019 2:34:30 PM`

and so I made this bash script but its not working.

`aws s3 ls --recursive s3://dentca-lab-dev-sample/2019-03-13/ | awk '$1 <= "2019-03-13 14:34:30" {print $4}'`

** `ls` is just for testing. will change it to `rm`

I also have this script for testing

`aws s3 ls --recursive s3://dentca-lab-dev-sample/2019-03-13/`

output:

```
2019-03-13 14:34:06   11656584 2019-03-13/mandibular.stl
2019-03-13 15:18:01   11969184 2019-03-13/maxillary.stl
2019-03-13 14:34:30    9169657 2019-03-13/obj.obj
2019-03-13 14:32:40   15690284 2019-03-13/upperAIO_50005.stl
```

but when I do the `awk` to make condition doesn't work. Maybe because `$1` only catches this arugment `2019-03-13` and im compering it to `2019-03-13 14:34:30`

also tried doing this. 
`awk '$1 $2 <= "2019-03-13 14:34:30" {print $4}'` to catch the second argument but still got nothing. Its my first to make a bash btw.

Thank you! I have this as reference btw. 
[aws cli s3 bucket remove object with date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375531/aws-cli-s3-bucket-remove-object-with-date-condition)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to obtain a list of objects with a `LastModified` before a given date:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "Contents[?LastModified<='2019-03-13'].[Key]" --output text
```

Note that it uses `s3api` rather than `s3`, which has access to more information.

You could then take the results and pump them into `aws s3 rm` to delete the objects.

Frankly, if you wish to get fine-grained like this, I would recommend using Python instead of bash. It would be something like:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

keys_to_delete = [{'Key': object['Key']} for object in response['Contents'] if object['LastModified'] < datetime(2019, 3, 13)]
s3.delete_objects(Bucket='my-bucket', Delete={'Objects': keys_to_delete})
```

Comment: im going to try this tomorrow but. how would you incorporate this with a ruby on rails backend? sorry im new to this dev ops thing.

Comment: [AWS SDK for Ruby Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/index.html#lang/en_us)

Comment: thank you for this. Upon researching last night I found out that you could do a lifecycle deletion on s3 files. Im recommending that for our meeting then if they won't accept it then our fall back is this. thank you sir!

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein - While running provided Python script, I am getting an error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable". Can you please help me.

Comment: @PardeepNaik Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old Question. You should include your [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error message you are receiving.

Comment: @PardeepNaik  the reason why you might be getting conflicting modules is that you have to import the datetime method from the datetime module.

E.G.
`from datetime import datetime`

Comment: I like the python solution here with boto3, thanks for reminding me there is more than one way to skin a cat!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to list files in the buckets modified before 2023-01-01 10:30:01

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://mybucketname/ | awk '$1 < "2023-01-01 10:30:01" {print $0}' | sort -n
```

after use rm in it to remove files

(WITH CAUTION, This won't ask you before deleting, and it's a simple way to accidentally empty your entire bucket, better to take a backup)

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://mybucketname/ | awk '$1 < "2023-01-01 10:30:01" {print $4}' | xargs -n1 -t -I 'KEY' aws s3 rm s3://mybucketname/'KEY'
```